# Does the Qur'an contain something similar to Christianity's "as you sow so shall you reap"?

Tags: quran, source-identification

Does the Qur'an have quotes which are similar to the following quote from Christianity?

> As you sow so shall you reap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [And that man will have nothing except that for which he has
>   endeavoured (to achieve);](http://quran.com/53/39) [And that his endeavor will eventually
>   be seen;](http://quran.com/53/40)

Source: [quran.com/53](http://quran.com/53) - [39](http://quran.com/53/39)/[40](http://quran.com/53/40)